# Google.proccess.gapps has stopped working

Tags: crashes

I have a Lenovo tablet and I updated the system. Now I keep getting the annoying messages, such as

> Google.process.gapps has stopped working

and

> Google play services are not working

I tried getting into the apps to uninstall Play Store and to clean the cache. It won't let me uninstall or clean the cache.

I don't have the regular settings like on a computer so I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Go to into settings/ application manager/scroll to left until you reach the all applications screen/ touch menu screen left of the home button/ reset app preferences.